# Rails ERB form fields rendered hidden

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have this form, and all of its element are rendered with the type="hidden", I don't know why this happens.

```
  <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
    <%f.text_field :username, :value => "Enter your user name", :class => "username-label" %>
    <span class="email-icon"></span>
    <% f.text_field :password, :value => "Enter your password", :class => "password-label" %>
    <% f.submit "LOG IN", :class => "login-button" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `<%` you are just executing the helpers.  You need to use `<%= ... %>` to output the result of those helper calls:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, :value => "Enter your user name", :class => "username-label" %>
  <span class="email-icon"></span>
  <%= f.text_field :password, :value => "Enter your password", :class => "password-label" %>
  <%= f.submit "LOG IN", :class => "login-button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Bad me, sorry for my novice question :D

Comment: @Wazery, no worries.  It happens sometimes!